# GroupBy classes in pandas with cumsum

Tags: python, pandas

a quick one but I am a bit stuck on this. I have a dataframe with 3 classes: 0, 1, 2. The idea is to calculate cumsum per each class using, possibly, groupby, although there could be some other way.

Here is my df:

```
| classes |
|    1    |
|    0    |
|    1    |
|    2    |
|    1    |
|    2    |
|    0    |
|    0    |
```

The 'ID' column I'd like to see:

```
| classes | ID |
|    1    | 1  |
|    0    | 1  |
|    1    | 2  |
|    2    | 1  |
|    1    | 3  |
|    2    | 2  |
|    0    | 2  |
|    0    | 3  |
....etc...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use cumcount here not cumsum :)

```
df['Id'] = (df.groupby('classes').cumcount() +1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) I believe:

```
df["ID"] = df.groupby("classes").cumcount() + 1
```

to get

```
    classes   ID
0          1   1
1          0   1
2          1   2
3          2   1
4          1   3
5          2   2
6          0   2
7          0   3
```